# Selenium open multiple Internet Explorer browser

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have Selenium automation framework, Cucumber with Serenity. Whenever I execute script, it opens up 6-7 different IE browser. Till now I have tried below things.
1. Enabled Protected Mode for all zone from Internet Options
2. Checked option "Reset zoom level for new windows and tabs" 
3. In my serenity framework I have set below IE driver capabilities in serenity.properties file:

```
<br> serenity.driver.capabilities="forceCreateProcessApi:true;
single-window:true;
nativeEvents:true;INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS:true;
IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION:true" <br><br>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.
Note : I am using Internet Explorer 11 on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest IE driver:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/